# コードをJupyter Notebookのファイルに保存してimportするとエラーになる

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

「みんなのPython」を参考にPythonの勉強をしているのですが、下記のコードを打ち込んでも、参考書に書いてある通りになりません。どこが間違っているでしょうか。
（juypter notebookを使って行っています）

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

class StrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        if not isinstsnce(key,str):
            raise ValueError("Key must be str or unicode.")
        dict.__setitem__(self,key.value)
```

これをstrdict.pyとjupyter notebookのファイルに保存して、

```
from strdict import StrDict
```

と次のセルで打ち込んだのですが、

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d320d56b1f78> in <module>()
----> 1 from strdict import StrDict

~\strdict.py in <module>()
      3   {
      4    "cell_type": "code",
----> 5    "execution_count": null,
      6    "metadata": {},
      7    "outputs": [],

NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

となりました。どうすればよいのでしょう？？

Answer (score 2):

> これをstrdict.pyとjupyter notebookのファイルに保存して、

ここが違っています。
Jupyter Notebook上で作れるのは、ipynb形式のファイルです。
strdict.py を作るにはJupyter Notebook以外のテキストエディタ等を使って作ってみて下さい。

---

もうすこし詳しく書くと、Jupyter Notebookの保存形式 ipynb の中身はjsonフォーマットです。これをPythonのimport文で読み込もうとすると、PythonがPythonの文法としてjsonフォーマットを解釈しようとします。Pythonの文法や組み込み変数に `null` は存在しないので、 `NameError: name 'null' is not defined` というエラーが発生しています。

Answer (score 2):

#### Jupyterでテキストファイルを作成する方法

Jupyter には Notebook（`ipynb`形式）ではないテキストファイルを作成・編集する方法もあるようです。書籍はこれを前提としているかも知れないので、[既にある回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/49414/3054) の補足とします。

新規にNotebookではないファイルを作成する際は、`Notebook:` ではなく `Other:` から `Text File` を選択します。

> [image: 新規ファイル作成メニュー]

上のようにテキストファイルを作成するか、既存のテキストファイルをクリックすると編集画面に移ります。Notebook を開いた際とは画面構成が異なるので、区別できると思います。

> [image: テキストファイル編集画面]

（操作方法やスクリーンショットはJupyter 4.4.0 のものです）

Comment: すいません遅れましたがmjyさんのやり方でできました。

Comment: お二方コメントをくださりありがとうございました！！！

Comment: @今井旬 こちらの回答で問題が解決した場合、回答についているチェックマークをクリックし、回答を「承認」いただけますでしょうか? システム的に、質問者さんにとってこの課題が解決済みであることを示すことができます。